# terms&service onload popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a terms and service popup as soon as the page loads how can I do that with html, javascript , css . please help.so basically  as soon as I load to my website there is a pop up with terms and service which I have ready .

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour] for guidance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

based on this reference - [codepen ref](https://codepen.io/rosybabu8/pen/MEmVVq)

```js
$(function() {
  var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
  overlay.show();
  overlay.appendTo(document.body);
  $('.popup-onload').show();
  $('.close').click(function() {
    $('.popup-onload').hide();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
    return false;
  });

  $('.x').click(function() {
    $('.popup').hide();
    overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -moz-opacity: 0.7;
  -khtml-opacity: 0.7;
  opacity: 0.7;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}

.cnt223 a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.popup-onload {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 101;
}

.cnt223 {
  min-width: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  min-height: 150px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 103;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px #000;
}

.cnt223 p {
  clear: both;
  color: #555555;
  /* text-align: justify; */
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.cnt223 p a {
  color: #d91900;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.cnt223 .x {
  float: right;
  height: 35px;
  left: 22px;
  position: relative;
  top: -25px;
  width: 34px;
}

.cnt223 .x:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<div class='popup-onload'>
  <div class='cnt223'>

    <p>
      Terms and conditions
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <a href='' class='close'>Close</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't take wild guesses at poorly-written questions. It encourages more such questions.